# Error: Attempt to read or write outside of partition after partitioning [fixed]

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount

I was partitioning my main drive from the command line on a USB drive, and used parted to take 75gb off the end of the main partition, when I had 100GB free. That was a success, and I was able to install OpenSUSE on the new partition, however now when I boot into Ubuntu (22.04) it gives the error message:
`Error: attempt to read or write outside of partition Press any key to continue`
After that, it prints out a block of text beginning `Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)`
and ends with a very similar message but beginning with `End kernel panic`

Upon running fsck, it prints another error message `Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.`

Unfortunately, a fresh install is not an option, so any help would be much appreciated.

Fixed now, thanks.

Comment: Have you booted a *live* system and checked you have no partition problems (corrupted file-systems etc.. ie. performing *file-system checks* using `fsck` or whichever command is appropriate for your file-systems; `fsck` only applies to some don't forget, with OpenSuSE defaulting to BTRFS).

Comment: The issue seems to be that I didn't correctly resize the filesystem to match the size of the new partition, and it is now too large.

Comment: Please delete the question. Or you may want to write an answer if you think others can learn from your mistake.